# MS Word compare style changes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

MS Word is good in comparing two versions of a document. The problem is Word does not show the text style changes. For example if I have a phrase with "MyWordStyle1" applied in initial document and in the updated version this same phrase with "MyWordStyle2" or without any style applied, it isn't be shown in the comparision.

Is there any way to track style changes? We have a lot of documents that differ not in text but in applied styles and we need to track a lot of such changes.

Answer (score 4):

How do you do comparison? I have compared two documents here and the style is reported to be different. I use `Review -> Compare` option. Perhaps you have wrong `Display for the review` option, which should be set to `Final: Show Markup`, NOT just `Final`. Here are the [example documents](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/JJoNsWoJnijiqQWsq6q3aA) and their comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When reviewing the marked-up changes to a document, be sure to click on "Show Markup" (in the "Review" tab) and ensure that "Formatting" is selected. Otherwise, Word intentionally filters out all formatting changes.